# node modules error when i add css into angular-cli.jon

Tags: angular

When i add `file.css` into `.angular-cli.jon`

```
 "styles": [
        "assets/css/file.css"        
      ],
```

and then run project with  `ng s -o` show this error in console

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/css/file.css
```

What's problem ?

Version :

```
Angular 5

npm version 5.6.0

node js v9.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Find my problem
In `file.css` i used incorrect direction `url`.